# RL0 file format

Tags: image, file, image-processing, satellite

What is a `.rl0` file format and how to access its data?

I have been searching for RL0 file format but what I get is `r10` and `rlo` file format and I am unable to get the data inside the file.

How to get the data inside the file?

Comment: Do you have any information about it? Where it is from, what software wrote it, what type of data in contains, ...

Comment: Try sharing a link to it (Google Drive, Dropbox, pastebin or somesuch) and maybe someone will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It is in hex format you can use the following code.

```
import binascii
with open (final_name, "rb") as myfile:
    header=myfile.read()
    header = str(binascii.hexlify(header))[2:-1]

print(header)
```

Comment: Do you have links for any `rl0` files and a description of them please, as you seem familiar with the format?

Comment: I have a file with a dataset it is a large file.